# How to scroll multiselect select after disable it with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am disabling select element using jQuery. select can be single or multiselect. In single select I have no issue because there is only one select. But in case of multi select when I am disabling it then the scrolling is not appearing. I am getting something like this

[image: disable multi select but no scrolling]

See Rooms has multiple options. But I am unable to scroll. How can I enable scrolling in this case. Here is my jquery code

```
function disableSelect($select) {
    if ($select.length){
        var $selectedOptions = $select.find(":selected");
        if ($selectedOptions.length) {
            $select.empty();
            $selectedOptions.each(function () {
                var $selectedOption = $j(this);
                var selectedOptionText = $selectedOption.text();
                var selectedOptionValue = $selectedOption.val();
                var option = ["<option value=", selectedOptionValue, ">", selectedOptionText, "</option>"];
            $select.append(option.join(''));
            });
        }
        $select.prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

I also tried some thing like this

```
...
$select.prop('disabled', true);
$select.css({
    'overflow-x': 'hidden'
});
```

But still no scrolling. How can I add scroll to my disable multi select ?
Thanks

Comment: disable the option not the entire select

Comment: @guradio yup now it is working. Thanks. I did something like this `if ($selectedOptions.length) {
   $selectedOptions.each(function () {
    var $selectedOption = $j(this);
    $selectedOption.prop('disabled', true);
    $select.append($selectedOption);
   });
  } else {
   $select.prop('disabled', true);
  }`. Now I can make Scroll. Thanks many :)

Comment: glad it works happy coding mate :)